# How to style this wp_list_pages markup

Tags: php, html, wp-list-pages

I'm wanting to custom style the output of this wp_list_pages $children echo, here is the code:

```
<?php
if($post->post_parent)
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
else
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
if ($children) { ?>
<ul class="submemu-children">
  <?php echo $children; ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

As you can see I've already added a class to the UL, but what if I want to dig a little deeper and add some markup around the $children in the echo?  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I would like to achieve something like the following:

```
<ul class="submenu-children">
<li><i class="icon-something"></i><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><i class="icon-something"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><i class="icon-something"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><i class="icon-something"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><i class="icon-something"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've temporarily appended the  makrup through jQuery, but I would like to know for future reference ideally.

Comment: It will more help if you give example of which markup you want to achieve

Comment: Sure will add now :)

Comment: do you want all "<i class="icon-something"></i>" diffrent?

Comment: Same is fine...

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0&link_before=<i class="icon-something"></i>');
```

define link_before property in wp_list_pages

Comment: did you try this code? define link_before parameter in wp_list_pages.by doing that you get you required output.

Comment: Will be checking it soon and will update you. Thanks @Ravs.